# Why is my custom shader causing flickering in my ARCore Light Estimation implementation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I'm developing an AR application using ARCore and Unity, where I'm trying to implement a custom shader to apply real-time lighting effects based on ARCore's Environmental HDR Light Estimation. The shader is supposed to adjust the lighting of my virtual objects based on the light estimation data from ARCore.

However, I'm experiencing a flickering issue where the lighting on my virtual objects rapidly changes between bright and dark.

Here's a simplified version of the shader code:

```
`Shader "Custom/EnvironmentLight"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                // Here's where I'm trying to apply the light estimation data
                col *= _GlobalLightEstimation; // _GlobalLightEstimation is a global variable that I'm updating in a script
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

In a separate script, I'm updating _GlobalLightEstimation based on the light estimation data from ARCore:

```
`void Update()
{
    // Get the light estimation data from ARCore
    Frame.LightEstimate.CalculateEnvironmentalHdrMainLight(out DirectionalLight, out AmbientSphericalHarmonicsL2);
    Shader.SetGlobalFloat("_GlobalLightEstimation", AmbientSphericalHarmonicsL2[0, 0]);
}
```

I've confirmed that the light estimation data from ARCore is being updated correctly, and the shader is being applied to my virtual objects. However, the flickering issue persists. Any ideas on what might be causing this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

ok- I figured it out--

I believe this was caused by the fact that Unity's rendering is not synchronized with the light estimation updates. As a result, the lighting values from ARCore might change rapidly between frames, leading to the flickering effect.

To address this issue, I went through a couple of approaches:

First I tried to use a Buffer or Smooth Transition:

Instead of directly applying the `_GlobalLightEstimation` value to the color of your virtual objects, you can use a buffer or smooth transition to gradually adjust the lighting over time. This can be done by introducing a damping factor or using a low-pass filter to smooth out the changes in the light estimation data.

```
    // In your separate script:
public float dampingFactor = 0.9f;
private float smoothedLightEstimation;

void Update()
{
    Frame.LightEstimate.CalculateEnvironmentalHdrMainLight(out DirectionalLight, out AmbientSphericalHarmonicsL2);
    float newLightEstimation = AmbientSphericalHarmonicsL2[0, 0];
    smoothedLightEstimation = Mathf.Lerp(smoothedLightEstimation, newLightEstimation, dampingFactor);
    Shader.SetGlobalFloat("_GlobalLightEstimation", smoothedLightEstimation);
}
```

That didn't seem to help so I tried to use AR Foundation, which provided built-in support for applying light estimation to AR scenes. Instead of manually updating the shader with the light estimation data, I enabled AR Foundation's light estimation features, and it automatically adjusted the lighting of my virtual objects based on the real-world environment.

This helped creat a smoother and more stable lighting experience.

To enable AR Foundation's light estimation, you can follow these steps:

- Add the AR Environment Probe component to your AR Session Origin GameObject.
- Enable the "Update Light Estimation" option on the AR Session Origin component.

Using AR Foundation's built-in light estimation helped resolve the flickering issue and provided a more realistic lighting experience in the AR application.

I then also applied smoothing directly in the shader to prevent abrupt changes in the lighting.

You can do this by using a combination of current and previous light estimation values and smoothly interpolating between them over time.
In your script, keep track of the previous light estimation value:

```
    private float prevLightEstimation;
private const float smoothingFactor = 0.9f;

void Update()
{
    Frame.LightEstimate.CalculateEnvironmentalHdrMainLight(out DirectionalLight, out AmbientSphericalHarmonicsL2);
    float newLightEstimation = AmbientSphericalHarmonicsL2[0, 0];
    float smoothedLightEstimation = Mathf.Lerp(prevLightEstimation, newLightEstimation, smoothingFactor);
    Shader.SetGlobalFloat("_GlobalLightEstimation", smoothedLightEstimation);
    prevLightEstimation = smoothedLightEstimation;
}
```

Then, in your shader, use the smoothed light estimation value:

```
    // In your shader
fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
    col *= _GlobalLightEstimation; // Use the smoothed light estimation value
    return col;
}
```

This worked for me- hope it works for others running into the same problem!